# How to add training end callback to AllenNLP config file?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, transfer-learning, allennlp

Currently training models using AllenNLP 1.2 and the `commands` api:

`allennlp train -f --include-package custom-exp /usr/training_config/mock_model_config.jsonnet -s test-mock-out`

I'm trying to execute a forward pass on a test dataset after training is completed. I know how to add an `epoch_callback`, but am not sure about the syntax for the `end_callback`.

In my `config.json`, I have the following:

```
{
...
"trainer": {
...
"epoch_callbacks": [{"type": 'log_metrics_to_wandb',},]
}
...
}
```

I've tried:

```
              "end_callback": [{"type": 'my_custom_function',},]
```

but got an illegal argument error. Also, I am not sure how I would accurately specify the exact custom function and communicate it to the trainer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create a new callback function/object that inherits from [TrainerCallback](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/main/allennlp/training/callbacks/callback.py) and override the `on_end` method, and then it should work as expected if you register it the same way as you did `log_metrics_to_wandb` above.

Comment: So should the key in the config be `on_end`? Or just by specifying the custom `TrainerCallback` that should be fine?

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure you'd add it like this:

`"epoch_callbacks": [{"type": 'my_custom_function',},]` and it should work as long as you override `on_end` in your custom `TrainerCallback` (and do whatever else you'd like to do in your custom callback).

Comment: Interesting, so it will still go under an `"epoch_callback"`?

Comment: I believe so, but I would recommend trying it and seeing if it works. `epoch_callbacks` takes a list of callback functions to call per epoch, so you should just be able to add your custom function there.

Comment: Hmm that's an interesting design - I guess you need to somehow keep track internally of the overall train progress, since the callback is repeatedly involved per epoch

Answer (score 0):

Just an example a bit more complete for people who is as lost as I am using allennlp, this worked for me:

Define the callback, *register it* and overwrite whatever method you want to call:

```py
from allennlp.training.callbacks.callback import TrainerCallback

@TrainerCallback.register("log_metrics_to_wandb")
class LogMetricCallback(TrainerCallback):
    def on_end(self, trainer, metrics, epoch, is_primary=True, **kwargs):
    ...
```

And add it in the config file under trainer -> callbacks

```json
{
...
"trainer": {
...
"callbacks": [{"type": 'log_metrics_to_wandb',},]
}
...
}
```

I tested it with version 2.4.0, but according to the documentation it should not have changed much.